# How to return Http Status-Line with Error Response?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, http, httpresponse

I am working on a Spring-Boot application. With each response I would like to return http Status-Line, Headers and Body. As per standards a Status-Line looks like: HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF.
For Example: Http/1.1 400 Bad Request

I am using ResponseEntity with VnDErrors but Status-Line is not forming as per standards. I am able to see only "Http/1.1 400". Here Reason-Phrase is missing.

I have tried with @ResponseBody with @ResponseStatus annotation but no luck to achieve desired result.

Here is piece of code which I am using:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException)
    ResponseEntity<VndErrors> httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.message)
        ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST).contentType(VND_ERROR).body(new 
        VndErrors(BAD_REQUEST, exceptionMessage))
    }
```

Expected reponse which conatins Status-Line: "Http/1.1 400 Bad Request"
Would like to know is this achievable? If yes, then how I can proceed to do same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard behavior of tomcat see [tomcat-8.5-changelog.html](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html)

[spring-boot-issue-6789](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6789)

> RFC 7230 states that clients should ignore reason phrases in HTTP/1.1 response messages. Since the reason phrase is optional, Tomcat no longer sends it. As a result the system property org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER is no longer used and has been removed. (markt)

Comment: Okay. But is there any way to send it in response. Might be programtically ?